# How to save data in local storage AND in session storage on Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, local-storage, session-storage

I would like to store user data and homepage categories in local storage and "permatheque" data in session storage. I tried to do something like this with vuex-persistedstate plugin on nuxt.js:

```js
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const dataUserAndHome = createPersistedState({
  key: 'vuex',
  storage: window.localStorage,
  paths: ['login', 'home']
})

const dataPermatheque = createPersistedState({
  key: 'perma',
  storage: window.sessionStorage,
  path: ['permatheque'],
})

export default ({store}) => {createPersistedState({
  plugins: [dataUserAndHome, dataPermatheque]
})(store)}
```

But it doesn't work everything is stored in local storage even the permatheque when I put the storage at `window.sessionStorage`:

Here is a `console.log` of session storage :

```
{
  "__nuxt_loading_screen_lastReloadTime": "1645621108799",
  "__nuxt_loading_screen_reloadCount": "1"
}
```

And here is a `console.log` of Local Storage :

```
{"vuex":"{\"home\":{\"category\":\"Perma'Thèque\"},\"login\":{\"user\":{\"user\":{\"id\":3,\"username\":\"admin\",\"email\":\"admin@bot.com\"},\"token\":\"842477516d0814ffd3fa740cd8811ef3bb6ad26f435221512e48cc2b095d53c9\"}},\"permatheque\":{\"category\":\"\",\"plant\":{\"id\":136,\"family\":{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"Lamiacées\"},\"category\":{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"Aromatics\"},\"name\":\"Basilic\",\"image\":null,\"facility_rate\":\"medium\",\"seedling_depth\":\"1cm\",\"seedling_distance\":\"15cm\",\"row_spacing\":\"20cm\",\"sunshine_index\":\"full_sun\",\"irrigation_index\":\"wet\",\"soil_nature\":\"light\",\"soil_type\":\"rich\",\"fertilizer_type\":null,\"acidity_index\":\"7.0 PH\",\"days_before_sprouting\":\"10jours\",\"average_harvest_time\":\"75jours\",\"soil_depth\":\"10cm\",\"plant_height\":\"25cm\",\"suitable_for_indoor_growing\":true,\"suitable_for_outdoor_growing\":true,\"suitable_for_pot_culture\":true,\"hardiness_index\":\"fragile\",\"no_of_plants_per_meter\":\"5\",\"no_of_plants_per_square_meter\":\"25\",\"min_temperature\":\"8°C\",\"max_temperature\":\"17°C\",\"time_to_transplant\":\"6semaines\"},\"letter\":\"C\"},\"i18n\":{\"routeParams\":{}}}"}
```

I do not understand.

Comment: Please use something other than an image to show what is in storage. For instance, `console.log(JSON.stringify(window.sessionStorage, null, 2))` will show what's in session storage, `console.log(JSON.stringify(window.localStorage, null, 2))`, what's in local storage. People who are visually impaired will not be able to understand a picture.

Comment: Also, [the NPM page for vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) says the package is deprecated, and its [GitHub repo is archived](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate). It may be time to move to a different package...

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok sorry i edited for the image, yes but I tried with the plugin Vuex-persist and it's the same problem but him it's not deprecated...